# ul <li> items not read by jaws

Tags: html, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to make a ul list read with jaws, but whatever i tried, it doesn't read the text content. 
How the list is currently defined:

```
<div class="facet-list-container expanded">
    <ul class="facet-list" id="facetList_32">
        <!-- ngRepeat: facetValue in getDateFacet(field) track by $index --><li class="facet-item ng-scope ng-hide" ng-repeat="facetValue in getDateFacet(field) track by $index" ng-show="facetValue.getCount() &gt; 0">
            <a tabindex="0" class="alist-group-item facet-link" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13) ? facetSelected(facetValue):return" ng-click="facetSelected(facetValue)">
                <span class="facet-label ng-binding">Oggi</span> <span class="facet-count ng-binding">0</span></a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

So it isn't reading the list element. 
What it reads is:

> Expand List Button expanded, Expand List

I tried to put an aria-label on the a tag, on both span elements, tried adding a title, adding the to te li tag,  but it never reads them.

Anyway tested with firefox 50.1 It was actually reading the a tag label. But if i test with Firefox 51.1 or Firefox ESR, i'm having this issue.

Do you know what could be the reason for that? 
The same snipped is read by chrome, and internet explorer without problems.

Comment: Do you have the rendered HTML of the page? Maybe a CodePen example or something? Remember, `<!-- ngWhatever` is a wrapper for code that itself is processed before being rendered, which is then what the screen reader parses. I need to see your rendered code.

Comment: i took it from inspect element in the browser, So i think this is the rendered code.

Comment: Do you have a URL with more HTML than that along with the script? For example, it can never announced "button" in your example since there is neither a `<button>` nor `role=button`. Also, have you tried JAWS with IE11? Typically a JAWS user does not pair with FF, but with IE11.